# Why do I get empty results using generated code from DB?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm using SQL Server 2005. I have a table `scores` with 6 rows and columns - `name, score` and `id`.

I added the data source with VS and it generated a dataset called `testDataSet`.

So I tried the following code which gives me zero results:

```
testDataSet db = new testDataSet();

var result = from row in db.scores
             select row.name;
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think I am...

Comment: In this case could you please explain, how exactly you generated a dataset called testDataSet within Visual Studio? And also what exactly did you mean by "I added the data source". Where did you add it and how?

Comment: Data -> Add new data source -> Database -> DataSet...

Comment: How do you know there are zero results?

Answer (score 1):

The probem you are having is that you are querying an empty `DataSet`.

You first have to create a connection to your `testDataSet` and fill the tables contained in it with data from your database.

If you have created `testDataSet` with the automated tools VS provides then the tool will have also created the relevant `TableDataAdapters` (in their own namespace) to fill and update your `DataSet`.

Initialize the relevant `TableDataAdapter` and fetch the data from the database with the `Fill(db)` method.

Comment: but doesn't that take all the db into my computer memory?

Comment: yes it does, but you can configure the `TableDataAdapter's` default `SelectCommand` (or add additional queries to your liking) to limit the scope of your query with `WHERE` clauses and the necessary `parameters`. Maybe you should also look into `LINQ to SQL` where you can directly use `LINQ` to query the `database context` in the way you seem to want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) is just a structured container for the query results, it has no connection to the data source (database). In order to populate the DataSet with data you need to use a [DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.aspx) with a [SelectCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand.aspx) and call the [Fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4b211hz.aspx) method.

```
var myConn = new SqlConnection ("..." );
var myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter ( "SELECT * FROM TableName", myConn );
var myData = new testDataSet( );
myAdapter.Fill ( myData, "TableName" );
```

Comment: I think he is using LINQ to SQL and testDataSet is not a data set at all but rather Linq to SQL context. This is confirmed by db.scores part of his example, where scores is the table name.

Comment: @zespri: Not necessarily. A strongly typed `DataSet` created with VS' automated tool will also contain a `DataTable` property **scores** which you can query in simily fashion.

Answer (score 0):

you sould query dataTable like this:

```
DataTable products = ds.Tables["Product"];

var query = products.AsEnumerable().
Select(product => new
{
    ProductName = product.Field<string>("Name"),
    ProductNumber = product.Field<string>("ProductNumber"),
    Price = product.Field<decimal>("ListPrice")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
scoresTableAdapter adapter = new scoresTableAdapter();
var result = from row in adapter.GetData() select row.name;
```

Others are right that your problem is that you are not querying the data. When you generated the dataset, an adapter is also generated for you, that will help you to query the data as shown above.