# Access to MS Access with C#

Tags: c#, .net, dataset, ms-access-2007

I've to retrieve information of an existing system which is using MS Access( :'( ).

So I added an existing Item(the mdb) to the project, and it created me a DataSet corresponding to all tables I've.

Once I've done this, I try to access to these data:

```
        ClsDataSet dataSet = new ClsDataSet();

        foreach (ClsDataSet.DOCDOCUMENTSRow docdocumentsRow in dataSet.DOCDOCUMENTS)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(docdocumentsRow.nom_document+"-->"+docdocumentsRow.nom_fichier);
        }
        System.Console.ReadLine();
```

Only to test...

But it doesn't enter in the foreach, it seems it thinks that the table is empty? I directly step on the ReadLine();

So did I missed something? I don't have any exception..

Should I load the table or something like this?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get empty results using generated code from DB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329781/why-do-i-get-empty-results-using-generated-code-from-db/6330052#6330052)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the snippet you have posted there isn't any `TableAdapter` that fills your schemas in the dataset you have created. `DataSet` is just a representation of what you have on db-side, so it is only a structure of db tables and doesn't directly contain data.

To fill your schema with database records you have to call `Fill` method of the associated `TableAdapter`. Usually it is created automatically by Visual Studio Designer when you drag-n-drop some database table in a `DataSet` schema (.xsd).

Comment: Okay, I was thinking it was working like Entity Framework. My DataSet schema has been generated by VS when I selected which table I want on my dataset. I found a "DBInfoTableAdapter", on which I can call a "Fill" method, but I can't found what i should put into this. I think it's something I can found in dataSet.DBInfo? But its a collection and I don't know which data I should put in there

Comment: For each Table there should be a corresponding TableAdapter. So, when you want to fill one table just call its associated adapter `Fill` method passing as parameter something like `myDataSet.myTable`. Please take a look at this article on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171920.aspx

Comment: I figured out, the things is that there is one adapter for each table :) So I found a DOCDOCUMENTSTableAdapter object, which accept my dataSet.DOCDOCUMENTS.

One last question, what is the effect of this, it's only a sort of binding, or it takes the totality of the database and put it in objects? What if I only want to work on some type of rows(e.g. which have the column A set to "XYZ")? Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: In your exemple, there is some other Fill methods, I don't have these kind of data, is it possible to tell to the generator that it has to generate this kind of methods? 
EDIT: Nevermind, I found this in the dataset schema

Comment: Actually it is not a direct binding, in fact if you want to reflect your dataset changes on database you have to call `Update` method of TableAdapter. If you want to work just on "special rows" the solutions are two (the second is preferred): 1 - Fill the table with all the db data and then filter results on dataset; 2 - Slightly modify the query associated with the `Fill` method adding a where clause;

Answer (score 0):

Just *creating* the data set using the constructor does not yet retrieve the data. You need code to *fill* (=> select the rows from the MDB file and store them within your data set instance) the data set first.

The easiest would be to create an ODBC connection to the MDB file and use `OdbcConnection` and respective `OdbsCommand` instances to create the actual connection and "SELECT" statements.

**EDIT**
You may be able to connect to the MDB file directly using the Table Adapter designer. You would then not need to create an ODBC connection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial about connecting to an Access DB - http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p4.html.  There is a link at the bottom to another page on that site on how to retrieve data.

Comment: I'm using code generated directly by VS, so I should not have to worry about con.open and things like this